# 24 hour notation for Time Field

Tags: 7, entities

I'm using [Time Field](http://drupal.org/project/timefield) to make a field in my event content type for the begin and endtime in of the event.
I know that when you outpout the time field via views, you can output it as 24h notation, which works fine. But I want to output the time using php in a tpl file 
using the row object. 
So I have php code in my views tpl file that says:

```
    <?php $uur  = $row->field_field_evenement_uur[0]['rendered']['#time']['value_formatted'];
          $uur .= ' - ';
          $uur .= $row->field_field_evenement_uur[0]['rendered']['#time']['value2_formatted'];  
?>
```

First thing that came to mind of course was go to `admin/structure/types/manage/my_content_type/fields/my_time_field` and set the field formatting to 24h notation. It simply looks though like it's not part of the configuration.

Then I debugged my `$row` output in my view to discover this other way to get a rawer sort of value for the time. This way I would write code like:

`$row->field_field_evenement_uur[0]['raw']['value'];`

So that would output the time value like `51600`. I've been looking for some formatter functions that I could wrap around this value and get me a 24hour notation, even from php.net but it's all seeming like it has to do with the `date();` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totally looked past the display fields part of the field configuration of fields ui. That's exactly where you can set it to output 24hr notation.